# Set up sky sphere to be bright white in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, skybox

I'm trying to set up a plain white background for my Unreal Engine 4 game. I've tried experimenting with the sky sphere (setting all colors to #FFFFFF and setting cloud opacity and star brightness to 0.0). The background remains a dull gray color at best. (If I add stars, the stars are bright white, against the dull gray background).

How do I set up the sky sphere (or perhaps atmospheric fog) to create a bright white background?

[image: White Sky Sphere]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've figured out what's going on here.

UE4 reserves the 'bright whites' for emissive surfaces and blooms, and the engine softly clamps 'normal' (#FFFFF) white surfaces to a dim gray. This helps really bright materials and effects stand out. It's handled by the tonemapper, which converts the scene from HDR to LDR.

There's an interesting forum thread on it here: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?51570-Washed-out-Colors-from-Tone-Mapping-How-bad-it-really-is-and-how-to-fix-it.

Here's a quote which explains the situation nicely:

"The current behavior is intended. The base color is a material attribute that combined with light (and view angle) becomes the HDR color which still needs to be tonemapped to become the LDR color so a monitor can display it. The tone mapping tried to be mostly linear but if the HDR input values get very bright it should softly clamp to white. This is needed as lighting can be brighter than 1 in many areas and we want to avoid clamping artifacts with that.

"The pipeline is setup to make it easy to get real (physically based) content. Having a different default (e.g. no tonemapper) would break that goal. We intend to make the tonemapper pass more programmable (You already can override the tonemapper pass creating a Postprocess Material replacing the tonemapper but getting access to the properties is very very limited) so for some applications this default behavior can be altered." - Martin Mittring (Unreal Engine Developer, Epic)

Further reading:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/106489/white-not-white-ingame.html
https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?99478-Struggle-Against-Tonemapper